# Cannot Create a Generic class of type Map.Entry

Tags: java, generics

I have a map and I want to make a `Collector` implementation that would take from map, an entry set, and set the keys / values inside another custom POJO. I thought what would be simple was to to make a generic class of type `Map.Entry`, but that doesnt compile. How can I do that?

I could rethink and design the solution in another way, but I would like to find out how to make a generic class of type an inner interface of another class, like this example.

```
public class TestCollectorImpl<Map.Entry> implements Collector<Map.Entry, CustomDataType, CustomDataType>{}
```

Looks like I cannot use the `.` in the `<>` and this does not compile.

Comment: Not used to posting a lot, the editor took out the generic types for some reason.. public class TestCollectorImpl<Map.Entry> implements Collector<Map.Entry, CustomDataType, CustomDataType>{}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
public class TestCollectorImpl<K, V> implements Collector<Map.Entry<K, V>, Foo, Bar>
```

Keep in mind that `TestCollectorImpl<Map.Entry>` is trying to define a **new** generic type parameter with the name `Map.Entry` (which is an invalid identifier due to the dot). You're also using the [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) of `Map.Entry` here: `Collector<Map.Entry ...`. You don't want to do either of these.

What you *do want* is two generic type parameters to pass along to be used as the types of the key and value of the entry.

Comment: Cool, I think that should work, and thanks explanation, sure does give me more clarity around generics even. PS, I up-voted, but they don't get shown apparently because of having a low 'rep'

Comment: @Amol That's ok. Happy to help.